# How to search using regex fast in mongodb using djongo in django

Tags: regex, django, mongodb, search, djongo

I have a table in DB with almost 20 million records. I want to search through regex. It was all good when the number of records were about 100 thousand. But now it takes like quite a lot time even sometime it results in timeout. Does I need to migrate to SQL database may be `postgresql` or something like elastic search. As the records in this table is expected to increase more than 20 billion. Can there is a way to make it efficient by keeping the same settings as I'm using `djongo` to connect `django` to `mongodb` or I have to use any other database for fast searching.

**My model schema is**

```
from djongo import models as model
class User(model.Model):
    email = model.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    source = model.CharField(default='unknown',max_length=150)
    username = model.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    hash = model.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    salt = model.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    ipaddress = model.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    lastipaddress = model.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    name = model.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    dateofbirth = model.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    phonenumber = model.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    firstname = model.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    lastname = model.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    address = model.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    objects = model.DjongoManager()
```

**This method is called when an post request is send to django**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAdminUser])
def search(request):

if 'username' in request.data:
    username = request.data['username']

if 'email' in request.data:
    useremail = request.data['email']

if 'userid' in request.data:
    userid = request.data['userid']

if 'query' in request.data:
    query = request.data['query']
else:
    return Response(status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

obj = {}
obj['query'] = query
obj['type'] = type
obj['wildcard'] = wildcard
obj['regex'] = regex
if not (type in ['email', 'domain', 'username'] and wildcard == 'false' and regex == 'false'):
    obj['request'] = request
final = []
print('wildcard', wildcard)
print('regex', regex)
print('type', type)
if wildcard == 'true' or regex == 'true':
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        t1 = executor.submit(getRecordsFromDB, obj)
        final = t1.result()

return final
```

**Called by the above method this where regex queries are performed**

```
def getRecordsFromDB(obj):
    max_limit = 10000
    if obj['wildcard'] == "false" and obj['regex'] == "true":
        print("yes regex thing")
        if obj['type'] == 'domain':
            obj['query'] = r'.+@{1}' + obj['query']
            obj['type'] = 'email'

        try:
            pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
            paginator = pagination_class()
            queryset = User.objects.mongo_find({
                obj['type']: {'$regex': obj['query']}
            }).count()
            if queryset > max_limit:
                return Response(status.HTTP_507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE)
            else:
                queryset = User.objects.mongo_find({
                    obj['type']: {'$regex': obj['query']}
                })
            page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, obj['request'])
            serializer = UserSerializer(page, many=True)
            return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
            return Response(status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

    elif obj['wildcard'] == "true" and obj['regex'] == "false":
        print("yes wildcard thing")
        #obj['query'] = obj['query'].replace('.', r'\.')
        obj['query'] = re.escape(obj['query'])
        obj['query'] = obj['query'].replace('\*', r'[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*')
        print('below is the respective regex for the given query')
        print(obj['query'])
        if obj['query'][0] != r'*' and obj['type'] != 'domain':
            print('yes here where it should not be')
            obj['query'] = r'^' + obj['query']
        if len(obj['query']) > 1:
            if obj['query'][-1] != r'*':
                obj['query'] = obj['query'] + r'$'

        print('final regex ', obj['query'])
        if obj['type'] == 'domain':
            obj['query'] = r'.+@{1}' + obj['query']
            obj['type'] = 'email'
            print('very final regex ', obj['query'])
        try:
            pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
            paginator = pagination_class()
            queryset = User.objects.mongo_find({
                obj['type']: {'$regex': obj['query']}
            }).count()
            if queryset > max_limit:
                return Response(status.HTTP_507_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE)
            else:
                queryset = User.objects.mongo_find({
                    obj['type']: {'$regex': obj['query']}
                })
            page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, obj['request'])
            serializer = UserSerializer(page, many=True)
            return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        except Exception as err:
            print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
            return Response(status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)

    return records
```

Comment: Basically `queryset = User.objects.mongo_find({obj['type']: {'$regex': obj['query']}})` is the query that takes long? Can you show us an example of `obj['type']` and `obj['query']` where the query takes a long time?

Comment: Yes exactly this query.

Comment: queryset = User.objects.mongo_find({ "email": {'$regex':  ".+@{1}@apple\.com$" }})

Comment: Have you indexed the `email`? I know indexing is part of the professional djongo package so it’s not free but it’s crucial at that scale.

Comment: I didn't. It's kinda expensive like paying 50$ per month.

Comment: That’s cheap. With the scale you’re talking about you won’t find any solution that doesn’t cost money. Elasticsearch in the cloud isn’t cheap either.